# Ajax call by HTTP request in angular 2

Tags: ajax, angular, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to load some user data from database to my angular 2 page. I am doing the angular 2 as separate application and using ReST APIs for get data. My back-end is designed using spring and spring boot and maven tool. So when I am using my angular 2 page, is it possible to load my data from spring boot micro services using Ajax call? Angular 2 supporting Ajax call for HTTP request?. If possible, can anyone share any reference link for exploring the Ajax with http request in angular 2?

Comment: See this page https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b

Comment: Go through HttpClient https://angular.io/guide/http. Use HttpClient rather than Http which will be depricated in furture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So when I am using my angular 2 page, is it possible to load my data
>   from spring boot micro services using Ajax call?

Yes, that's what Angular is built for, single page applications which calls back Restful services for data. Only thing is I wouldn't phrase it as AJAX call (sounds like an old school :) ) I would rather call it as REST service call.

> Angular 2 supporting Ajax call for HTTP request?

Yes it does, that's what Angular is built for

> If possible, can anyone share any reference link for exploring the
>   Ajax with http request in angular 2?

Any sample Angular App with a backend will serve as an example. You will be able to find lots of examples by just googling it. Even if I am providing the code here, it will become irrelevant overtime as angular library itself is evolving. So, I would say, wise thing to do is, check their official website (angular.io, not angularjs that's angular 1.X, ancient stuff) and look for http call examples (eg. tour of heroes project).